# Python Whoosh not accepting single character

Tags: python, whoosh

I am trying to parse a query which has text plus number.

Example: Apple iphone 6 results in:

```
  Results for And([Term('title', u'apple'), Term('title', u'iphone')])
```

while Apple iphone 62 results in:

```
  Results for And([Term('title', u'apple'), Term('title', u'iphone'), Term('title', u'62')])
```

Why isn't it accepting single digit number?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I checked out whoosh via mercurial and can't reproduce:  `p = whoosh.qparser.QueryParser("field", None)`, `p.parse('htc one 8')` leads to `And([Term('field', 'htc'), Term('field', 'one'), Term('field', '8')])`

Comment: It is based on what Analyzer you chose for the `field`. Single char are considered as stopwords in the standard analyzer, check my answer

Comment: @blackmamba please check my answer and consider to upvote/mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

All words with single-character is considered as stop words in Whoosh by default and ignored. This means all letters and digits are ignored.

> stop words are words which are filtered out before or after processing of natural language data (text). [(ref)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words)

You can check that [`StopFilter`](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/api/analysis.html#whoosh.analysis.StripFilter) has a `minsize = 2` by default added to pre-defined set.

```
class whoosh.analysis.StopFilter(
        stoplist=frozenset(['and', 'is', 'it', 'an', 'as', 'at', 'have', 'in', 'yet', 'if', 'from', 'for', 'when', 'by', 'to', 'you', 'be', 'we', 'that', 'may', 'not', 'with', 'tbd', 'a', 'on', 'your', 'this', 'of', 'us', 'will', 'can', 'the', 'or', 'are']),
        minsize=2,
        maxsize=None,
        renumber=True,
        lang=None
        )
```

So You can resolve this issue by redefining your schema and removing the `StopFilter` or using it with `minsize = 1`:

```
from whoosh.analysis import StandardAnalyzer
schema = Schema(content=TEXT(analyzer=StandardAnalyzer(stoplist=None)))
```